# Cannot add value of tye HyperLink to a InlineCollection of TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I get that error in this code:

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run>let me</Run>
   <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">google</Hyperlink>
   <Run>that for you</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

If it isn't possible to add hyperlinks why it is available inside TextBlock?

**Context:**
I want to show some reviews inside a `LongListSelector`. reviews may contain links, I can use `RichTextBox` but I think it is not optimized for `UI and Data Virtualization` inside `LongListSelector` so I prefer to use `TextBlock`

```
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Reviews}">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text={Binding Review}/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Try adding `Target="_blank"` in `<Hyperlink />`.

Comment: Err....I thought it's `HyperlinkButton`. You can't use that, you have to go for `RichTextBlock`. Check out [this](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2013/05/30/win8xaml-how-to-create-a-textblock-with-clickables-hyperlinks-in-it/)

Comment: There is no `RichTextBlock` in windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the "text with hyperlink" to <s>RichTextBlock</s> `RichEditBox` using dependency property. It will convert each hyperlink into `HyperlinkButton`. I recommend you to customize `RichEditBox` such that it looks like more `TextBlock`. Also customize `HyperlinkButton` to look inline.

```
public static class NavigationService
{
    // Copied from http://geekswithblogs.net/casualjim/archive/2005/12/01/61722.aspx
    private static readonly Regex RE_URL = new Regex(@"(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?");

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Text",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(NavigationService),
        new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTextChanged)
    );

    public static string GetText(DependencyObject d) { return d.GetValue(TextProperty) as string; }

    public static void SetText(DependencyObject d, string value) { d.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }

    static Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text_block = d as RichTextBox;
        if (text_block == null)
            return;

        text_block.Blocks.Clear();

        var new_text = (string)e.NewValue;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(new_text))
            return;

        // Find all URLs using a regular expression
        int last_pos = 0;
        foreach (Match match in RE_URL.Matches(new_text))
        {
            // Copy raw string from the last position up to the match
            if (match.Index != last_pos)
            {
                var raw_text = new_text.Substring(last_pos, match.Index - last_pos);
                //text_block.Inlines.Add(new Run(raw_text));
                //var paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = raw_text });
                if (text_block.Blocks.Contains(paragraph))
                {
                    text_block.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
                }
            }

            // Create a hyperlink for the match
            var link = new HyperlinkButton()
            {
                Content = match.Value,
                NavigateUri = new Uri(match.Value),
                Margin = new Thickness(-20, 0, -20, -15),
                FontSize = 20,
                TargetName = "_blank"
            };
            link.Click += OnUrlClick;


            var inlineUi = new InlineUIContainer();
            inlineUi.Child = link;
            if (!paragraph.Inlines.Contains(inlineUi))
            {
                paragraph.Inlines.Add(inlineUi);
            }
            if (text_block.Blocks.Contains(paragraph))
            {
                text_block.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
            }

            //text_block.Inlines.Add(link);

            // Update the last matched position
            last_pos = match.Index + match.Length;
        }

        // Finally, copy the remainder of the string
        if (last_pos < new_text.Length)
        {
            //var paragraph = new Paragraph();
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = new_text.Substring(last_pos) });
            text_block.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
        }
    }

    private static void OnUrlClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var link = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
        // Do something with link.NavigateUri otherwise by default it would be open in IE.
    }
}

<RichTextBox local:NavigationService.Text="{Binding Review}" IsReadOnly="True" />
```

Code copied  & tweaked from [here](https://github.com/MaxSchmeling/flamecage/blob/master/GrayHills.FlameCage.Client/Core/NavigationService.cs)

Comment: `RichTextBlock` doesn't exist in Windows Phone :| and that code is for 2005 :))

Comment: Ah, please wait I am converting code for WP, I hope it will work.